# Initializing boost date to the first year of AD

Tags: c++, boost, gregorian-calendar, boost-date-time

I would want to initialize a gregorian date like this

`boost::gregorian::date d = { 1, 1, 1 };`

but `year = 1` is not allowed.
How can I create a day before Jesus was born ?

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of Gregorian date supports dates in the range 1400-Jan-01 to 9999-Dec-31. So handling a date outside this range is no directly possible.